# What is the best way to draw 4bpp 2D tiles with multiple palettes?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, graphics, nintendo

I'm creating a generic SNES tilemap editor (similar to [NES Screen Tool](https://shiru.untergrund.net/pic/nesst.png)), meaning I'm drawing a lot of 4bpp tiles. However, my graphics loop takes too long to run, even with `CachedBitmaps`, which can't have their palettes changed, of which I may need to switch between 8. I can deal with the SNES format and size of things, but am struggling with the Windows side.

```
// basically the entire graphics drawing routine
case(WM_PAINT):{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);
    graphics.Clear(ARGB1555toARGB8888(CGRAM[0]));   // convert 1st 15-bit CGRAM color to 32-bit & clear bkgd
    
    // tileset2[i]->SetPalette(colorpalette); // called in tileset loading to test 1 palette
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++){
        tilesetX[i] = new Gdiplus::CachedBitmap(tileset2[i], &graphics);
    }
    
    /* struct SNES_Tile{
        uint16_t tileIndex: 10,
        uint16_t palette: 3,
        uint16_t priority: 1, // (irrelevant for this project)
        uint16_t horzFlip: 1,
        uint16_t vertFlip: 1,
    }*/
    // I can see each individual tile being drawn
    for(int y = 0; y < 32; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++){
            // assume tilemap is set to 32x32, and not 64x32 or 32x64 or 64x64
            graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(tilesetX[BG2[y * 32 + x] & 0x03FF], x * BG2CHRSize, y * BG2CHRSize);
            // BG2[y * 32 + x]  & 0x03FF    : get tile index from VRAM and strip attributes
            // tilesetX[...]                : get CachedBitmap to draw
        }
    }
    
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

I am early enough in my program that rewriting the entire graphics routine wouldn't be *too* much of a hassle.

Should I give up on GDI+ and switch to Direct2D or something else? Is there a faster way to draw 4bpp bitmaps without having to create a copy for each palette?

### EDIT:

The reason my graphics drawing routine was so slow was because I was drawing directly to the screen. It is **much** faster to draw to a separate bitmap as a buffer, then draw the buffer to the screen.  
Updating the tile's palette when drawing to the buffer results in perfectly reasonably speeds.

Comment: on windows side use 24bpp or 32bpp true color for editing and rendering. You just load/save 4bpp indexed ...

Comment: @Spektre So then I should create a copy of each bitmap for each palette?

Comment: You are allocating 1024 `Gdiplus::CachedBitmap` objects for each pass through `WM_PAINT` (which may or may not ever get released). Memory allocations are pretty expensive operations, you certainly don't want to perform this for each render pass.

Comment: To use the GPU instead of the CPU, you could use DirectComposition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/july/windows-with-c-embracing-the-windows-composition-engine or Windows.UI.Compositon https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/62923cdacaba28fedc4f3dab6e0c12ec (which is DComp evolution) both usable with classic win32 desktop apps. Each tile could be a DComp "visual" which can be drawn using Direct2D. And you could use a shader for your ARGB1555toARGB8888 conversion. But that probably requires a substantial rework of your graphics pipeline.

Comment: @はるき You got more palettes for each image? that is weird ...

Comment: @Spektre Well, as this is a SNES tilemap editor, and the SNES has 8 palettes for the background, of which is selected _per tile_, not per bitmap, that would necessitate 8192 bitmaps, instead of 1024 (not to mention that the SNES can also flip tiles horizontally and vertically, bringing the worst-case scenario to 32768 bitmap for _**one**_ tileset, of which there are 2).